# Convert Japanese kanji into furigana using Natto gem (Mecab)

Tags: ruby, mecab

Using Natto gem (MeCab) is it possible to convert a mixed katakana/hiragana/kanji/alpha string to katakana/hiragana/alpha? (i.e. converts the kanji).

For example I need to convert this text:

`日本語だぜ、これが。
   これはカタカナである。
   こいつはEnglish alphabet charsなのです。
   ＡＢＣ１２３てのは全角英数字です。`

into this:

`にほんごだぜ、これが。これはカタカナである。こいつはEnglishalphabetcharsなのです。ＡＢＣ１２３てのはぜんかくえいすーじです。`

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it can read your mind enough as to do `すーじ`.

Comment: Do you have a limited number of Kanji that you would include, or would you want to translate Kanji into Hiragana at large? The problem with this is that most Kanji have multiple readings so you would have to match them against a dictionary like WWWJDIC that could convert the Kanji, and even then there would still be exceptions. Even a Kanji as simple as 一 ("one") can be read a multitude of ways. Coverting between Hiragana and Katakana can be done in Python using jcconv and I think Perl has a module, but Kanji would definitely need a source since the reading changes based on context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Author of the [natto rubygem](https://github.com/buruzaemon/natto) here. Thanks for using natto!

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to convert only the kanji characters into their corresponding hiragana (furigana) characters. The Ruby extension library NKF allows you to transform katakana into hiragana, and since MeCab yomi is by default returned as katakana, you could combine natto and NKF to convert the yomi readings for kanji only, leaving the other characters (hiragana, katakana, full- and/or half-width chars) as-is.

The key is to use natto to node-parse the input, and examine the char type value for each MeCab node. If the node's char type value is 2, that corresponds to a kanji node. You could then obtain the katakana yomi value from the MeCab node, and then use [NKF to convert the katakana yomi into hiragana](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/nkf/rdoc/NKF.html#method-c-nkf).

I just put up an [example on the natto wiki](https://github.com/buruzaemon/natto/wiki/%E6%8C%AF%E3%82%8A%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B).

Hope that helps!

Comment: the example has been moved to github [https://github.com/buruzaemon/natto/wiki/振り仮名変換](https://github.com/buruzaemon/natto/wiki/振り仮名変換)

Comment: @alanho, ah yes, I just recently migrated over to github from bitbucket. thx for pointing this out.